# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS SOCKS5 with Putty problem

Tags: ssh, proxy

I was running a Ubuntu 14 LTS server and used Putty to use SOCKS5 proxy for my web browser.
I just upgraded (fresh install) to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Now my browsers can no longer access the internet using SOCKS5 proxy.
The config of putty and the browser are not changed (only user account).

I scanned my local port on my client, which should be opened by putty (8080 in my case) and it is open indeed.
Any idea how to troubleshoot that?